# Open turkeys too soon

Tags: turkey, brining

We opened our turkeys and put them in a bucket of ice water.

I have not added herbs and salt yet, but there is a week before Thanksgiving.

Will the turkeys be ruined if I add the brine now? Should I add the brine just a day before Thanksgiving?

Comment: How big is the turkey?  Larger turkeys actually take a long time to thaw: https://www.goodhousekeeping.com/holidays/thanksgiving-ideas/a33825235/how-to-thaw-frozen-turkey/  (although those charts are for fridge, not ice water baths)

Comment: In other words, first pack your bird again in a large bag or several layers of plastic wrap, then come back here and [edit] your post with more details. Unless you have a bird the size of a hog, cold water thawing almost a week before cooking the bird will almost certainly get you in “unsafe” territory as far as food safety is concerned.

Comment: And welcome to Seasoned Advice! The [tour] and the [help], especially [ask], will get you started here.